# Can I use WordPress to power a PyPI documentation page?

Tags: python, wordpress, python-3.x, distutils, pypi

You can upload documentation to run alongside a package on PyPI, but i was wondering if those docs could be hosted using WordPress. The requirements call for a recent copy of PHP and a MySQL database. Does the PyPI documentation system provide this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three kinds of documentation associated with a PyPI package.

---

First, there's the documentation on the package page itself.

This is just your `long_description`, parsed as ReStructured Text. So, that documentation cannot be served by WordPress.

I suppose you could indirectly pull it from a WordPress site if you set up the site to present a plain-text or RST version of your docs, and did something like this in your `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    # ...
    long_description = urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com/path/to/mydocs').read()
)
```

… but I don't think you want to do that.

---

Next, you can add documentation at `pythonhosted.org` by uploading files from your package's `pkg_edit` page, or by using the `upload_docs` feature in `distribute`/`setuptools`.

This is just a tree full of static pages. So, that documentation cannot be served by WordPress.

However, again, you could use WordPress to generate this documentation, then pull it down and submit it to PyPI. And here, it seems less like a bad idea.

---

Finally, you can add a home page, which is a link to any site you want.

This can, of course, be a WordPress site.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I suppose I could restart my blog and use it, in fact that might not be a bad idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan2055: If you look around, the vast majority of packages use their `README.rst` or `README.txt` as the `long_description`, and use a home page link and/or a link within the `README.rst` itself for the more detailed docs. So, you won't be in bad company if you do things that way.